# Can I mock calling class of method partially

Tags: java, mockito

I want to mock a method of calling class, is that possible in Mockito

Here is sample code:

```
private ChecksUtil serivce;
```

I want to mock only `serivce.method(`) not the whole class.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done.  You would use spy.

```
ChecksUtil service = spy(new ChecksUtil ());

when(service.method()).thenReturn(someObject);
//or if method is a void
doNothing().when(service).method();
```

A spied object leave the object alone except for any methods that you want to mock.